# Unable to cast json value

Tags: c#, json, xml, casting

I'm unable to cast values from json object in to variable.

Here is my json which comes in either of two formats and I always wanted to retrieve the format 1 values and whenever I get format 2 values I just have to igonore executing the assignment to my local variable.

1.

```
<Parameters>
      <Param1>"aa9c1b47dfc946f396038b6462700e8c"</Param1>
 </Parameters>
```

2. 

```
<Parameters>
      <Param1>{"Code":"12345"}</Param1>
 </Parameters>
```

Here is my code to fetch GUID value

```
public static void GetCodes(string code, string msg, params object[] usrLogData)
        {
var proposalId = string.Empty;
 proposalId = (string)userLoggingData.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

However I'm getting a below exception when I get the second format XML value
**Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'.**

I tried with Dictionary and Regex still didn't worked.

Comment: `var proposalId = usrLogData.OfType<string>().DefaultIfEmpty("").First()`?

Comment: This worked for me.. Thanks, can you explain me how OfType<string>().DefaultIfEmpty("") works

Comment: It means, "return all values `v` in `usrLogData` such that `v` is a `string` and, if there are no such values, return a singleton sequence containing the empty `string`"

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to parse XML into your variable?

For example 1, the parameter is in XML and not json.

For example 2, you perhaps need to pass "{"Code":"12345"}" as your parameter, as that is the json object you mentioned..

Moreover, you can try newtonsoft library to parse json into your variable..

```
try
        {
            //your working code
            var tempproposalId = string.Empty;
            tempproposalId = (string)userLoggingData.FirstOrDefault();
            //your working code
            Guid proposalId;
            if(!Guid.TryParse(tempproposalId, out proposalId))
            {
                //failed to parse GUID, wrong format.. IGNORE
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //here catch the wrong format for second data,.. you can just ignore it if you wish
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm looking forward to cast or assign value to proposalId only if I get first XML format data and I have to reject or neglect whenever I came across with second XML format data.

Comment: I would prefer if you can upload the sample code and parameter that you are working with to give a more understanding on your problem.
anyway, if your solution already working for first format data, you can just put try,, catch.. then you just ignore if any exception is thrown.

to validate the first format, you can use
Guid guidResult = Guid.Parse(inputString)